# Error when trying to create Android Menu in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

Morning,
I am very new to Java and have previously only used HTML/Javascript when creating Android Apps.
Updating my Android app using Eclipse and phonegap.

Trying to create a menu following [this tutorial](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/building-native-menu-with-phonegap.html).

I get an error in my mainActivity class:

> the method startactivity(intent) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (intent)

Here is my code:

```
package co.uk.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import co.uk.xxxxx.xxxxx.R;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/start.html");
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.settings:
            this.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            this.appView.sendJavascript("navigator.notification.alert('No help')");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I do have strings.xml and menu.xml

The error is at the line `this.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));`

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @AmolTate as mentioned in the start of my post "the method startactivity(intent) is not applicable"

Comment: I think you extended DroidGap class instead of Activity

Comment: Just change extends Activity instead of extends DroidGap

Comment: Changing from DroidGap did not solve the error, but added a few more (probably because super.loadUrl needs DroidGap)

Comment: I dont have much Idea about phone gap. But that feature is working on 2.8 & later version of phone gap

Comment: Remove all imported file and import it again it one-by-one